# Best way to put a embedded video next to text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had several attempts at doing this, but just couldn't get it quite right. I want the video to be responsive when the browser shrinks and eventually stack when the browser gets small enough, like if it were an image that I put into a bootstrap grid, but I cannot figure out how to do this with an embedded video. Here is my html. I really need help with the css. [image]

```
<section class="section1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row section1Row">
      <div class="col-md-6 section1Text">
        <h2 class="text-center">What We Have to Offer</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel massa iaculis, posuere augue et, pharetra ipsum. Suspendisse metus ex, pellentesque id dolor in, vehicula varius tortor. Nam auctor ante nisi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe width="672" height="378" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bsY2GdBEvSA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a responsive design you want to mess with CSS media queries : [using media queries - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Also, read the full [Google Web Fundamentals course](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/), it will help.

### TL;DR

1. Choose your breakpoints ([choosing breakpoint](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/how-to-choose-media-queries-breakpoints-to-best-support-all-connected-devices)):

   - Don’t use popular screen sizes for breakpoints
   - Choose content-driven breakpoints
2. Use CSS `@media (max-width: 800px) { ... }`

   - Target media types ([media types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_types)) or features ([media features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_features))
   - Test `media queries`: [testing media queries - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries)
3. Mess with `flex-direction: row`